# Accessing a Pervasive 13 Database for Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-server, pervasive

I've successfully installed the Pervasive 13's 64bit Client onto Ubuntu Server 18.04.

How can I now establish a connection to the Pervasive 13 server (which is installed on a Windows 2008 R2 server) and perform a sql query?

I'm extremely confused by the documentation, which directs me to the [bcfg](https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/#page/advops%2Fconfig_client_security.htm%23ww184196) tool after client installation. I'm not clear if that tool is for configuring the server or for setting up the client connection. Ether way, the documentation is too abstract for my comprehension; I need concrete examples of someone successfully establishing a connection to (at least a hypothetical Pervasive server located at some hypothetical ip address) and NOT JUST abstract syntax that never shows an example of SQL statement being submitted from command line Linux.

Seriously, the documentation covers so much detail of stuff I don't immediately care about, that I can never seem to figure out my practical needs which are to simply establish a connection to the database, perform a SQL query, and get a result set.

The installation of the client should have sensible defaults, and the documentation, after installation, should focus on getting you connected and running sql statements as quickly as possible, instead of going on and on about details that are only of interest if the defaults aren't sensible. Let me connect first! Then if I have a problem, only then do I care to learn further detail about other aspects of configuring the connection.

Pervasive is such an obscure database server, that I'm left with only this documentation to figure this out. Any other database would probably have YouTube videos that show you how to install the client, and start making some SQL queries and getting result sets.

Someone at Actian, ought to be kind enough to make a quick start video for the client on Ubuntu Server that quickly covers installation and finishes where you're submitting sql queries and get result sets. After all, that's the purpose of database client.

Can someone please provide some concrete examples of how I can turn this successful installation into a relationship with the database server where I can submit SQL queries and receive result sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the documentation points to `bcfg`.
If the Client is installed and didn't display any errors, you need to add an ODBC DSN using `dsnadd` (https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/index.html#page/uguide%2Fuguide.dsnadd.htm%23ww68699).  An example of creating a client side DSN pointing to a remote database is:

```
dsnadd -dsn=clientDemodata -db=Demodata -host=WindowsServerName
```

(where clientDemodata is the DSN created on the Linux box, Demodata is the PSQL database on the remote server called WindowsServerName).

Once the DSN has been added, you should be able to use `isql` or `isql64` (https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/index.html#page/uguide%2Fuguide.isql.htm%23ww138933) to execute a query.
Running isql / isql64 with just the DSN will let you execute SQL queries interactively:

```
isql64 clientDemodata
```

An example of running isql using a file as input for the SQL statement(s) is:

```
cat two-queries.sql | isql clientDemodata -b
```

If you've done all that, what errors or behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Thank you so much for getting my further. I'm still having issues, but I will submit them in another question.